# Jenkins same parameters on multiple jobs

Tags: jenkins, parameters

we have many Jenkins Test Jobs dependening on one library. Every Job has multiple parameters  (always identical).

Now the problem is that if we change or add an parameter in the library, we have to touch every single jenkins job configuration.

Is there a way to configure the parameters of multiple jobs in a central place? Like defining the parameters in a file and refering to that? or is there jenkins plugin for that use case?

Thanks,

Marco

Answer (score 3):

You can edit parameters (and much more) of multiple jobs in one place with [Configuration Slicing Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuration+Slicing+Plugin):

> Job Parameters (aka "This build is parameterized") can be configured across multiple jobs at one time through the "Parameters" link. To indicate which parameter you are configuring, note the "JobName[ParameterName]" syntax.

Not sure if this can help if you use some advanced parameters like File parameter, Dynamic parameter etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [Build Flow plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin)

You can run same or multiple jobs many times with different configuration.

2. Use [Multijob Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) and [parameterized plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)

You can pass different parameter  by using these plugins